# Int value not being accepted

Tags: c++

I'm doing homework in C++ that I need to validate an ID but I cannot understand why this value can't be read or used inside this if.

I have an ID value (string) passed by the user and I need to check if it begins with 'Y' or 'y' and ends with 'K' or 'k' and also has 8 characters.

I already tried dni[dni.size()] , dni[sizeof(dni)] , dni[aux]

```
//Función que valida un DNI que es pasado por parametro. Retorna un booleano
bool testeDNI(string dni){

    bool check = false; 
    int aux = dni.size();
    cout<< "Valor DNI: " <<aux<<endl;

    if(dni[0] == 'Y' || dni[0] == 'y' && dni[dni.size()] == 'K' || dni[dni.size()] == 'k' ) {  
        std::cout << "***************************************"<< endl;
        std::cout << "*            DNI VALIDO               *"<< endl;
        std::cout << "***************************************"<< endl;
        check = true;

    }else{
        std::cout << "***************************************"<< endl;
        std::cout << "*          DNI NO VALIDO              *"<< endl;
        std::cout << "***************************************"<< endl;
    }
    //Retorna el valor de check
    return check;
 }
```

The only way that I can make this work is by using a number. "inside dni[7]"

Comment: Not really the answer, but `string[string.size()]` is out-of-bounds...  Indexes for `string`, `vector`, etc are `0...size()-1`.

Comment: Also not really the answer, but that first if statement will never be true...

Comment: The first character has index 0; the last has index `size()-1`. Just like with arrays.

Comment: Because of [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) a condition like `A || B && C || D` is equal to `A || (B && C) || D`. Think about that regarding your condition.

Comment: But when I put the value here "int aux = dni.size();" it shows me an int value .

Comment: @GabrielVendramini Yes, the size is still a valid integer. It's not a valid index through.

Comment: You got a lot of hopefully helpful answers now. If none solve your problem, feel free to ask. If you find the answers helpful, you should upvote and if your problem is solved, you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
 if(dni[dni.size()] == 'Y' || dni[dni.size()] == 'y' && dni[dni.size()] == 'K' || dni[dni.size()] == 'k' )
```

`dni.size()` is the character "behind" the string! If you want to check the first char, you simply have to write `dni[0]` and the last character is at `dni[dni.size()-1]`.

And as mentioned by comment, you have to talk care about [operator precedenc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) which results in a different order of evaluation as you expect. So add some braces like:

Attention: Only ONE of the first 2 lines are needed, see comments on it

```
if(
   ( dni.size() ) && // check for empty string to prevent UB in following comparisons OR!!!
   ( dni.size() == 8 ) && // if you already have the need to check for a given length requirement 
   ( dni[0]            == 'Y' || dni[0]            == 'y' ) && 
   ( dni[dni.size()-1] == 'K' || dni[dni.size()-1] == 'k' )
   )
```

Answer (score 3):

The first character has index 0; the last has index `size()-1`.
Just like with arrays.
Accessing `dni[dni.size()]` is either out-of-bounds and undefined, or will give you zero, depending on the standard.

Also, your condition suffers from a predence problem: `a || b && c || d` is equivalent to `a || (b && c) || d`.

If you use `front` and `back` instead of indexing, you can write almost exactly your own description of the condition, and you can take advantage of the standard library to avoid the precedence problem:

```
if (dni.size() == 8 && std::tolower(dni.front()) == 'y' && std::tolower(dni.back()) == 'k')
```

(Note that you need to check the size first in order to ensure that the string is not empty.)

Comment: You seem to be the only one who picked up the `dni.size() == 8` requirement :-)

Answer (score 2):

To access the first character you can use `dni.front()` or `dni[0]` and for the last character `dni.back()` or `dni[dni.length() - 1]` or `dni[dni.size() - 1]`. That is because the first index is 0 and thus the last index is length - 1.

Also you should use parantheses in your `if`. `if(a || b && c || d)` will actually evaluate as `if(a || (b && c) || d)`.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes start at 0, So if you want to index the last character of a string you have to index the length of it -1.

For example, let string S = "hello!"
S[0] = 'h'
Size of S is 6, but the highest index is `S[size-1]` which is `S[5]` = '!'
To fix your code, you must change dni[dni.size()] to dni[dni-size()-1].

Comment: What do you mean by `S[0] = '!'`?

Comment: typo, I meant h

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to all, with your help I could finish the list of exercises yesterday. I also will ask my teacher if I can use the method that puts the entire string to lower case, which will cut a lot of redundancy.

```
//Función que valida un DNI que es pasado por parametro. Retorna un booleano
bool testeDNI(string dni){   
    bool check = false; 
    //El primer carácter tiene índice 0; el último tiene un tamaño de índice 
    //() - 1. Al igual que con los arrays.
    if(dni[0] == 'Y' || dni[dni.size()-1] == 'y' && dni[0] == 'K' || 
dni[dni.size()-1] == 'k' && dni.size()-1 == 7) {  
        std::cout << "***************************************"<< endl;
        std::cout << "*            DNI VALIDO             *"  << endl;
        std::cout << "***************************************"<< endl;
        check = true;

    }else{
        std::cout << "***************************************"<< endl;
        std::cout << "*          DNI NO VALIDO              *"<< endl;
        std::cout << "***************************************"<< endl;
    }
    //Retorna el valor de check
    return check;
 }
```